# Emacs to autocomplete all imported module functions

Tags: emacs, elisp, rope, ropemacs, pymacs

I have been using rope, ropemacs and pymacs for my autocompletion. It does pretty well, but I noticed that there is some limitation to the amount of completion it aids in. It only seems to complete the classes for the modules imported not all of the functions available.

How can I get my pymacs, ropemacs, rope to look up all of the functions of an imported module?